# VBScript convert date to string

Tags: string, date, vbscript

So I have a possibly simple question that I can not find the answer to.

I am writing a VBScript that will move a subfolder from one folder to another.  When moving I want to append the date onto the subfolders name.  I have everything working, except I can not figure out how to convert the date to a string so that it can be added to the folder name.

```
curDate =  Month(Date) + "_" + Day(Date) + "_" + Year(Date) + "_" + Time

If  fs.FolderExists(rsltFldrPath) Then

'Grab folder and Subfolders
Set fldr = fs.GetFolder(rsltFldrPath)
Set subFldr = fldr.SubFolders

For each folder in subFldr
    moveTo = archFldrPath + "\" +folder.name + curDate
    fs.MoveFolder folder, moveTo
Next
End If
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The string concatenation operator in VBScript is "&", so a quick fix would be:

```
>> curDate =  Month(Date) & "_" & Day(Date) & "_" & Year(Date) & "_" & Time
>> WScript.Echo curDate
>>
7_22_2011_5:32:55 PM
```

If you specify the **exact** desired result, I'm willing to propose a better way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Hm...well my main goal is to have a folder called "Results"  To end up being called "Results_Month_Day_Year_Time"  So that when I move it there is no other possible files that it will overwrite.

Comment: What about the space after "Results"? Do you want the PM/AM? Should the day and month be zero padded?

Answer (score 3):

**Ekkehard.Horners** answer won't work as Time needs to be reformatted to remove the colons (:) Folders cannot have colons.

Try;

```
curDate =  Month(Date) & "_" & Day(Date) & "_" & Year(Date) & "_" & Time

Replace(CurDate,":","-")
```

I'm sure there's a more succinct answer but that will work also padding shouldn't be an issue as the underscores will negate duplicate possibilities.

I wanted to comment but don't have enough rep.

Comment: Thanks that was really accurate!